# Nodes do not save, but instead redirect to edit page again

Tags: 7

When my client, using her account, attempts to save a node, she is sent back the node edit page without any error messages. The node is not saved. The problem doesn't seem to happen when she plays back the audio in the AudioRecorderField on the node before saving, but not every node needs audio. Any ideas?

Fields on node:

1. Entity Reference to 'subheading' node
2. title
3. taxonomy
4. other taxonomy
5. filefield with audio recorder widget from AudioRecorderField
6. plain old filefield

Comment: Its a hard one to answer without seeing any log reports and so on, however I have had a similar problem in the past when a rule isnt set up correctly for "On saving new content/Updating content".

Comment: I don't have rules installed. :(

Comment: What module is the field from? Are there any other fields on the node? What are the logged error messages?

Comment: Edited question to clarify.

Comment: No logged error messages.

Comment: Do you get any error message indicating X field can not be blank or an specific value like a number or text? Do you have any module that alter the node form and inject to extra validation?

Comment: No error messages that I see.

Comment: Try creating another content type and add the same fields one at a time and adding some content after each one until you hit the field which is giving you drama. Then at least you have a question that can be answered.

Comment: I figured it out. It was the AudioRecorderField. I replaced it with the standard AudioField and it worked fine.